# Rewrite this function as DB query?

Tags: java, sql

I'm cleaning up my code, should i change the following function to a MySQL query? If so what would be a nice MySQL function to achieve this functionality?

```
public ArrayList getNewTitles(ArrayList candidateTitles, ArrayList existingTitles) {

    ArrayList newTitles = new ArrayList();
    Movie movie = new Movie();
    boolean isNew = true;

    for(int i=0; i<candidateTitles.size(); i++) {

        for(int j=0; j<existingTitles.size(); j++) {

            movie = (Movie)existingTitles.get(j);

            if(((String)candidateTitles.get(i)).equals(movie.getRawTitle())) {
                isNew = false;
            }

        }

        if(isNew == true) {
            System.out.println("newTitle for crawling: " + (String)candidateTitles.get(i));
            newTitles.add((String)candidateTitles.get(i));
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("candidate binned: " + (String)candidateTitles.get(i));
        }


        isNew = true;

    }

    return newTitles;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing your table structure, I would guess it might be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title NOT IN (SELECT title FROM existingTitles);
```